# How to put an icon on file extensions of a Qt program on Windows Explorer

Tags: c++, qt, file-extension, qt-installer

[Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ebv4qvol49rrqd3/SP.rar?dl=0) is the program. On the Web I found:

```
QSettings reg("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Classes\\.sp\\DefaultIcon",
                 QSettings::NativeFormat);
reg.setValue("Default", "C:\\Users\\Tomy\\Desktop\\package_directory"
               "\\packages\\com.vendor.product\\data\\Spreadsheet.ico");

SHChangeNotify(SHCNE_ASSOCCHANGED, SHCNF_IDLIST, NULL, NULL);
```

I put this in `void MainWindow::writeSettings()` and `void MainWindow::readSettings()` in the code. And then created an installer using Qt Installer Framework and installed it on Windows.
No icon! Any idea?

**EDIT:**
I this time removed the code above from both `void MainWindow::readSettings()` and `void MainWindow::writeSettings()` functions and added it to the *MainWindow*'s constructor body, then re-did the rest and installed that new on my Windows.
Again, no changes in result.
There might be a problem either in the code or the script file. I'm using Qt 5.9.